# How does django authentication work internally?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I was looking under the hood, on how the different authentication systems work in django. I have a basic idea that in case of session authentication, sessions are stored some where in the session models. It is easier to understand token authentication, as in token authentication, tokens are created which are in turn stored in the frontend. But, how is the login saved when the user goes for basic authentication or session authentication?

When using basic authentication, assuming the `User` that is imported in `from django.contrib.auth.models import User`, we can use the decorator `login_required`, but how exactly does it work?

Comment: This is probably too broad for Stackoverflow. A session token is saved in the backend (usually your database). A cookie is set on the frontend to track your session and passed between frontend and backend

Comment: When you login, Django creates a session object in the database and a cookie for referencing that session (which is stored in the browser). The `login_required` decorator is a wrapper (like any other decorator), for telling Django to checks for the cookie data sent on the request and validate it belongs to a session stored in the database. With this, it can know which user that session belongs to and validate whether the view should return a valid response or not.

Comment: I got the idea, but then what is the difference between session authentication and django basic authentication? As session object would be created in the case of session authentication, right?